# Alignment in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and export of my code like this picture

[image]

Now I want to move my text to the right of the List,How can i do it?

Comment: Change the gravity of your `TextView` to `right`.
You could also try `layout_marginLeft`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Hola mundo"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your `TextView` should probably do it:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

That sets the width to the whole row size (otherwise the gravity attribute won't work - in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Set the table row width to match_parent
and set the android:layout_gravity="right" to the textview to align right of the table row

Try using weights

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/chuck_desert"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"> but doesn't change in my export

Comment: set the android:layout_gravity="right" to the textview

Comment: <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
but doesn't work again

Answer (score 0):

Change attribute gravity to layout_gravity in your TextView, ["gravity"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity) specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view and ["layout_gravity"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

Also change its value from "center" to "right".

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Comment: i change my code,,,but doesn't any change to my export

Comment: @AliSaravani also change the table row:
`<TableRow
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">`